# getElementById Function on Node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to build a `node.js` app and I just tried to insert a `getElementById` function inside `window.onload`. When I intend to make `node index.js` the code below;

```js
var http = require('http');

function handler(req, res) {

  var form = '';
  if (req.method == "GET") {

    form = '<!doctype html> \
    <html lang="en"> \
    <head> \
        <meta charset="UTF-8">  \
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="text/html"> \
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"> \
        <title>XYZ HR</title> \
    </head> \
    <body> \
      <form name="myForm" action="" onsubmit="return ajax();"method="post">\
          <br> \
          <input type="file" id="myResume" accept=".txt,.doc,.docx,.pdf,.jpg"> \
      </form> \
      <hr> \
      <button type="submit" id="submitBTN" onclick="">Submit</button> \
      <div id="displayResume"></div> \
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script> \
      <script> \
        window.onload = function () { \
            var myResume = document.getElementById('
    myResume '); \
```

> Is that not working on `node.js` to define elements server-side? It
>   produce an error on the terminal like below and I couldn't find a
>   proper example with same error.

```
/Users/erhanyasar/Documents/Web/www/arete/HR/node/index.js:30
    var myResume = document.getElementById('myResume'); \
                                            ^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:53:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:95:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:543:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:423:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:147:9)
```

Comment: It looks like you have a floating backslash after `getElementById`, unless that's part of the error message.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Node.js is a server-side language and doesn't have a document-object.

Comment: @FrederikHansen I guess so it doesn't have. I just wanted to create a form input like file-upload and define the upload button id..

Comment: @ErhanYaşar This isn't typical how you would make a website in Node.js. I would recommend you look into the Express-framework, as that makes things a lot easier. Have a look at [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_express_framework.htm) for an introduction.

Comment: Tx pal, I'm on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is no problem in server side rendering in nodejs. Just use any template engine for that, like http://olado.github.io/doT/index.html. They have great example on how to do it.

Comment: I'm looking for more examples to get the point but if I can do it by templating why not to define this way? Is that not possible to take user input with node or what is the restriction in my case defining user input file upload?

Comment: Of course you can. Check examples on the page, that I gave. Whatever template engine you will use is up to you, but it is very inefficient to write pure html as a string. So usage of template it very common practice for server side rendering. Also it is called "template" because it takes variables (user input in your case)

Comment: I used templating before for javascript but not with node. I'll change it and make it work anyway. Thanks for your effort, I learned a lot but I think the answer should contain "why upper code doesn't work syntically or semantically" as my main objective when asking so I didn't accept fyi.